# ObjectIDs and uniqueness within a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So this is a thought experiment:

ObjectIDs in mongo have 24 characters so if you're building URIs with them it can become cumbersome.

each character is base 16 so, if we get the last 8 digits it would allow us for 16^8 (4,294,967,296) unique combinations.

according to the [ObjectID specification](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) it is consisted by:

> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
>   a 5-byte random value,
>   a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

would it be guaranteed that, within a collection, if we use the last 4 bytes - 8 characters - we would have a unique value for each document?

So this way i could create an .id property on the model, assign it on .pre('save') and create an index on the property for the collection(s).

I have tested and confirmed it works with 12,856,767 documents and plan to test it to exhaustion, but would like to know an experts opinion, am i totally off on this?

Answer (score 4):

As per the documentation of mongodb [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid):

> While ObjectId values should increase over time, they are not
>   necessarily monotonic. This is because they:
>
> - Only contain one second of temporal resolution, so ObjectId values created within the same second do not have a guaranteed ordering, and
> - Are generated by clients, which may have differing system clocks.

So this in a nutshell says that you have no 100% guarantee of uniqueness when it comes to ObjectId. Basically, there is a chance of collision, particularly for ObjectIDs generated by the same host within the same second at a high volume.
In almost all of the scenarios (as you have also seen with your 13M records) this is not an issue but still there is a chance ...

However [Timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html#timestamps) within a mongo instance is **guaranteed to be unique**.

> BSON has a special timestamp type for internal MongoDB use and is not
>   associated with the regular Date type. Timestamp values are a 64 bit
>   value where:
>
> the first 32 bits are a time_t value (seconds since the Unix epoch)
>   the second 32 bits are an incrementing ordinal for operations within a
>   given second.
>
> **Within a single mongod instance, timestamp values are always unique.**

Although it clearly states that this is for `internal use` it maybe something for you to consider if looking for trully unique value is what you are after.

Comment: Akrion I get that the timestamp bits can repeat if several items are created at the same second, but i'm not using those bits, i'm using some of the "random" ones and the sequential ones...

Comment: i'm not arguing, i'm just trying to get to the bottom of this :)